# Prompt for Unsaved Profile change and add a second Save Profile button

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, confirmation, profile-edit

I changed my profile picture and noticed it didn't take affect. I made sure it wasn't caching and tried again... and again, and again.

After uploading the picture for the 5th or 6th time I realized there must be a Save button that I can't see somewhere... sure enough, there is a Save button hidden from my view that requires me to scroll to the bottom of the page to see.

**Feature request #1:** Prompt the user when they are leaving the Edit Profile page with unsaved changes, similar to when you leave a page with an unposted comment or answer.

**Feature request #2:** A second Save button that is at the top of the page.

<sub>Mockup:</sub>

[image: Mockup illustrating that the Save button isn't visible with a mock Confirm Navigation box and second Save button.]

Comment: An alternative solution might be to display the save buttons at *both* the top and the bottom.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That is exactly what #2 asks for, a *second* button which is at the top.

Comment: Oops >_< Time for coffee!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker here is [fitting coffee, in the spirit of Meta](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/64/bf/79/64bf791b2e9f340f374065fe21041c3f.jpg). ;)